# How to save the output files in the corresponding folders

Tags: bash

I have many allsamples.bam files in different folders and I want to extract unmapped reads from all of them and save it as unmapped.bam in the corresponding folders, how to do it? allbamfiles.txt contains the paths to all my bam files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#$ -q cluster
#$ -cwd
#$ -N test
#$ -e /path/to/log
#$ -o /path/to/log
#$ -l job_mem=8G
#$ -pe serial 4

SAMTOOLS="/path/to/samtools"

while IFS= read -r file
    do
            $SAMTOOLS view -b -f 4 $file > "${file%.bam}_unmapped.bam"
    done < "/path/to/allbamfiles.txt"
    wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the paths of all files in allbamfiles.txt are refered to the current directory or are absolute paths this solution should work.

Notice that the dirname command gets the path of the file and the basename command gets the file name.

```
SAMTOOLS="/path/to/samtools"
while read file; do
  dir=$(dirname $file)
  fileName=$(basename $file)
  $SAMTOOLS view -b -f 4 $file > "${dir}/${fileName%.bam}_unmapped.bam"
done < "/path/to/allbamfiles.txt"
```